# Django form_valid() doesnt work, AbstractUser, Class Based View

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm Try to create Registration Form With Django.
But When i try, Form Doesn't Work, The Data not send to Database.
I Know Why the form can't work, because method **form_valid** is not Executed, maybe the requirment is not completed.
My Question Is How do i know it's not working ? Where i found the error ?.
This is my code.

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email                   = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=150)
create_account          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_reviewer             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = CustomAccountManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

def __str__(self):
    return self.full_name
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['full_name'].widget.attrs.update({
        'required' : '',
        'type'  : 'email',
        'placeholder' : 'Nama Lengkap Anda',
    })
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({
        'required' : '',
        'type'  : 'text',
        'placeholder' : 'emailanda@universitasmulia.ac.id',
    })
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({
        'required' : '',
        'type'  : 'password',
        'placeholder' : 'Password',
    })
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({
        'required' : '',
        'type'  : 'password',
        'placeholder' : 'Konfirmasi Ulang Password',
    })

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ("full_name", "email", "password1", "password2")
```

views.py

```
class RegistrationView(FormView):
template_name   = 'authentication/registration.html'
form_class      = RegistrationForm
success_url     = '/authentication'

def form_valid(self, form):
    messages.success(self.request, 'Please Check Your Email For Infomation Detail!')
    print('Success Created Your Account')
```

registration.html

```
<form method="POST" class="register-form" id="register-form">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                            {{form.email}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                            {{form.full_name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                            {{form.password1}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="re-pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                              {{form.password2}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term" class="agree-term" />
                            <label for="agree-term" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>Saya Menyetujui Peraturan <a href="#" class="term-service">Dokumen Ini</a></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-button">
                            <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Register"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: to see the errors put ```{{ form.errors }}``` in your template

Comment: @Sumithran Thanks For The Answer, Now I Know What's The Problem.